# How to make matplot charts with varying amount of rows?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
dim=len(filtered_df[hu].unique())+len(filtered_df['Cat1'].unique())
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [10, 6]
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True
ydim=math.ceil(dim/4)

fig, axis= plt.subplots(ydim, dim, squeeze=True)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=1, wspace=1)
for ax in axis:
    ax.set_ylim(0,100)
    ax.set_xlim(-1,4)
```

If ydim = 1 the axis object has shape (4,), so the for loop addresses each subplot.
However, if ydim is 2 the shape of axis becomes (2, 4), so I would have to write the for loop for axis[0] and axis[1].
No, setting squeeze to True, or False does not change this behaviour.

So how can I set the parameters of my plot, without knowing how many rows I need?

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood the behaviour and purpose of "squeeze". It's default is "True", and setting it to "False" results in you having consistent dimensionality of the axis array, which solves the problem.